# Unity desktop and mouse sensitivity

Tags: unity, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only show Unity laucher when left cmd/win key is pressed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96410/only-show-unity-laucher-when-left-cmd-win-key-is-pressed)

I keep accidentally moving the mouse too far to the left of the screen which brings up the unity "taskbar". Is there a way I can disable mouse over and strictly use the "function/windows" key to bring up that taskbar? It's kind of an annoyance to have it come up inadvertently all the time. Not to be too critical the more I use unity the more I grow to like it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure if this is what keeps biting you in Unity, check the windows mouse over setting.

System -> Preferences -> Windows
In the Windows Preferences dialog, uncheck the box next to "Select windows when the mouse moves over them"  That would force mouse click to raise windows.  I am not sure if Unity bypasses this setting to always give the taskbar when you go offscreen left.